# Phpunit check methods call order independent on other calls

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to ensure, that in one of the mocks two methods are called in specified order: methodB() is called **after** methodA().
I can achieve something similar with `->at()`, e.g.:

```
$service->expects($this->at(0))->method('activate')->with(
    $this->equalTo($activationKey)
)->willReturn(TRUE);

$service->expects($this->at(1))->method('getDetails')->with(
    $this->equalTo($activationKey)
)->willReturn($details);
```

But in case later in the code some call will be added before `activate()`, test will fail and I need to put then magic numbers into `at()`.

In my test I don't care, what is called before, after or between these two methods. I just want to ensure, that `getDetails()` is called **after** `activate()`.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look to phake that permit you to [Verifying Calls Happen in a Particular Order](http://phake.readthedocs.org/en/latest/method-verification.html#verifying-calls-happen-in-a-particular-order)